# Como abrir o app gmail pelo celular

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu sei que para abrir o maps é assim:

```
window.location = "geo:?q="+endereco;
```

Para abrir a discagem de telefone é assim:

```
 window.location = "tel:"+telefone1;
```

Para abrir a tela de mensagem(sms):

```
window.location = "sms:"+telefone;
```

Agora, como faço para abrir o email?

Comment: Já tentou `window.location.href = "mailto:user@example.com"` isso deve abrir o cliente default de email do usuário...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Chrome no Android está bloqueando os redirecionamentos para os aplicativos que não são feitos por meio de um gesto do usuário.

Sendo assim, via javascript não é possível redirecionar o usuário para o aplicativo de e-mail, isso desde o Chrome 40, somente se você colocá-lo por exemplo em um botão href, que funcionará quando o usuário clicar no botão.

[Aqui tem uma discussão sobre o assunto no fórum do Chrome.](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=477456#c5)

Se você inspecionar o elemento vera uma mensagem como

> Navigation is blocked: mailto:?...

---

Você pode tentar fazer desta forma, como citei antes que é adicionando um href.

```
var email = document.createElement('a');
email.style.visibility = 'hidden';
email.style.position = 'absolute';
email.href = 'mailto:email@gmail.com?subject=subject&body=body';
document.body.appendChild(email);
```

E após isso quando você for executar pode fazer assim.

```
email.click();
```

Comment: Valeu, era isso mesmo!